# Call base class method with enum parameter with "derived" enum

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

my question looks like a duplicate of about a million questions found on SO but I can't find a satisfying solution.

I'm currently working on a little import/export dll for a specific file format which is build in a block-like structure with different types of blocks referencing each other.

**EDIT**: Each block type has its own functionality and provides different information with different data types and so on. So they're not just giving aliases for their links. Sorry about that confusion, I broke them down to be as simple as possible to just describe the problem I have.

So every block of data has some information and holds a list of links to other blocks (which may be empty). Links are just 64bit values representing the absolute byte offset inside the file.

A typical case for inheritance: BaseBlock and some derived block types.

As every block can have some links I gave my base class an array of links and implemented a method that returns a link specified by an enum acting as a "named index":

```
typedef uint64_t LINK;

class BaseClass
{
public:
   enum BlockLink;
   LINK getLink(BlockLink link) {
      if(m_link_count < link) {
         return m_links[link];
      }
      return 0;
   }

private:
   LINK* m_links;
   uint64_t m_link_count;

}
```

In every derived class I would then define this enum just like:

```
Class ABlock: public virtual BaseBlock
{
public:
   enum BlockLink {
      link_to_f_block = 0,
      link_to_another_f_block = 1,
      ...
      link_to_d_block = 5
   }
}

Class BBlock: public virtual BaseBlock
{
public:
   enum BlockLink {
      link_to_nice_a_block = 0,
      link_to_evil_h_block = 1,
      ...
      link_to_strange_t_block = 5
   }
}
```

That would make accessing a link elegant by just using:

```
ABlock* aBlock;
...
/* some stuff that initializes aBlock */
...
LINK linkToDBlock = aBlock->getLink(ABlock::link_to_d_block);
```

The user would see there is an enum for accessing links and he doesn't need to know the index or stuff, while I wouldn't need to implement a method for each link in every derived block to get a self explaining way to access them.

Unfortunately this doesn't work as these enums are not compatible. So doing this I'm getting something like

> The argument of type "ABlock::BlockLink" is not compatible with parameter of type "BaseBlock::BlockLink"

So, is there an elegant way of doing something like that? Something like a "named access" or whatever you would call it?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Derived structs only create an alias for the enums BlockList? Do they provide any other functionality?

Comment: @Amadeus Sorry, yes they do. Every block type has some specific functionality and provides different information. They have only a header and a "link section" in common.